# How can I accept invitations for Game Center?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I'm working on my first multiplayer game for iPhone. I have everything working fine but I can't seem to get invitations working properly. When I send a invitation I will receive it on the other device in the statusbar, but If i click on it nothing happens. Do I need to implement the alert view too or is that already implemented?

Comment: Did you register for the invitation listener: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayerListener_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html